# Нужно ли отдельно удалять объект, переданный в protobuf класс с помощью метода set_allocated_...()? В с++

Tags: c++, google-protobuf

Нужно ли отдельно удалять объект, переданный в protobuf класс с помощью метода set_allocated_...() или данный указатель вычищается в деструкторе ?

Comment: [Тот же вопрос на английском.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960999/protobuf-will-set-allocated-delete-the-allocated-object)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, благодарю.